# How to write keypress event for DataGridTextBoxColumn

Tags: c#, winforms

I working on a code that have below given scenario

```
public class myGrid : System.Windows.Forms.DataGrid
{
     ......
     ......
}

public class cboDataGridBitCheckbox : System.Windows.Forms.DataGridTextBoxColumn
{
    private static int count = 0;
    private Int16 mi_flagbitvalue=0;

    public cboDataGridBitCheckbox() : base () 
    {            
        count ++;           
    }

    protected override void Edit(CurrencyManager source, int rowNum, Rectangle bounds, bool readOnly, string instantText, bool cellIsVisible)
    {

    }
}
```

and these control used in a form example ucCust.

```
public class ucRegCustomers : myGrid
{
   ...
   System.Collections.Hashtable lst = new System.Collections.Hashtable();
   cboDataGridBitCheckbox bCheckbox = 
   new cboDataGridBitCheckbox();
   bCheckbox.FlagBitValue = 2;
   bCheckbox.HeaderText = "Mejlavisera";
   lst.Add("flag",bCheckbox);

   ucRegGrid.CreateColumnStyles(lst);
}
```

So here by using `ucRegGrid.CreateColumnStyles(lst)` function the we are creating check box control for flag column.

Problem: Whenever the `CurrentCellChanged` event fired in `myGrid` 
`cboDataGridBitCheckbox` Edit ("protected override void Edit") function gets called
but I want to restrict the edit function to call when the keyboard "tab, navigation arrow keys pressed". For example for only mouse event the edit function should call.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Click on your grid. press F4 one window will come that is properties. There 4-5 buttons are there A-Z with arrow mark etc. In thatClick 4th one that is events there double click on keypress event then write your code.

Then use the following condition in keypress or keydown or keyup event

```
 if (Keys.Tab != e.KeyCode)//with && add other condition for your other keys
```

Comment: I want to control the edit function of DataGridTextBoxColumn by above suggestion i can write key press event for mygrid only but to handle edit function of DataGridTextBoxColumn its little bit complecated by datagrid keypress event

Comment: see i edited my answer you can use that if condition.

Comment: Actuly u r suggesting add the keypress event in datagrid but my edit function that i need to control is in "cboDataGridBitCheckbox" which is automaticaly called after CurrentCellChanged of datagrid by adding key press event is it possible to control edit method of cboDataGridBitCheckbox ?